# I got error when I try to connect to my WebService on Windows-XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, webserver

When I try to connect to my WebService I get this:

```
Server Application Unavailable 
The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.
Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request. 

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.
Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

And the log is:

```
aspnet_wp.exe could not be launched because the username and/or password supplied
in the processModel section of the config file are invalid.
```

And this:

```
aspnet_wp.exe could not be started. the error code for the failure is
80004005. this error can be caused when the worker process account
has insufficient rights to read the .NET Framework files.
please ensure that the .NET Framework is correctly installed and that the ACLs on the
installation directory allow access to the configured account.
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is the official Microsoft response titled: [FIX: ASP.NET does not work with the default ASPNET account on a domain controller](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315158) which suggests several workarounds to your problem.

---

But i would take a look at [this](http://balajiramesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/aspnet_wpexe-could-not-be-launched-because-the-username-andor-password-supplied-in-the-processmodel-section-of-the-config-file-are-invalid/) down-to-earth resolution to the error.

Steps for `Setting the userName attribute to SYSTEM in the <processModel> section of the Machine.config file` :

- Locate Machine.config, it could be in this location : `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config`
- Now change the ProcessModel entry to this: `<processModel userName=”SYSTEM”/>`
- The restart IIS using `Start -> Run -> IISRESET`